# Finding duplicates in multi-row SQLite-table

Tags: list, sqlite, duplicates

I want to manage lists with a various number of entries. Currently I am using the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE lists (
    list_id INTEGER,
    sort_id INTEGER,
    content_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (list_id,sort_id)
)
```

So I can call an individual list using:

```
SELECT content_id WHERE list_id=<<X>> ORDER BY sort_id
```

In principle adding a new list is not a problem, but how can I check for duplicates of a complete list before inserting a new set of a list? I give an example:

There is the following list already inserted:

```
list_id | sort_id | content_id
--------+---------+-----------
    3   |    1    |     7
    3   |    2    |     4
    3   |    3    |     9
```

A new list with the content 7,4,9 would be an duplicate and must not be inserted. But the content 4,7,9 or 7,4 or 7,4,9,5 must be insertet due to my definition of a different list-content.

I thought of adding a new table, that contains the concatenated content of a list, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE lists_concat (list_id PRIMARY KEY, content_concat UNIQUE)
```

So for my example there would be the entry

```
list_id | content_concat
--------+---------------
    3   |     7,4,9
```

This would work, but it seems to be very complicated. Is there an easier way? I am also open to use another table structure for my lists. Tell me please about your ideas.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two list are equal if

1. the number of `sort_id`s is equal, and if
2. the values for all `sort_id`s match, i.e., there are no rows with matching `sort_id`s but different values.

Assuming the new list is stored in a separate table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_list ( sort_id, content_id );
```

You can search for duplicates like this:

```
SELECT list_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT list_id
      FROM lists) AS L1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM lists as L2
       WHERE L2.list_id = L1.list_id
      ) =
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM new_list
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM lists AS L3
                  JOIN new_list ON L3.list_id = L1.list_id
                               AND L3.sort_id = new_list.sort_id
                  WHERE L3.content_id != new_list.content_id);
```

Comment: **! ! ! The right parenthesis of the second to last line is wrong ! ! !** But thanks for the solution. I can use that!